# Pagination not existing on all queries

Tags: php, instagram-api

Taken from an older stack overflow question (sorry for not posting link but stack overflow says  that i must have more than 10 rep for more than 2 links) to generate Instagram access tokens so they will be out of sandbox mode. So finishing with the above, i have the following two queries:

1. `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' . 'wordcamp' . '/media/recent?client_id=' . 'one_id' . '&access_token='. $accessToken . '&count=' . $count`
    In the one above the pagination comes up ok where in this one
2. `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='John'&access_token=$accessToken&count=$count` 
    It is not shown at all. With pictures the first one is like: 
   [image] where the second is like [image]

Why in the second link i do not have the pagination option?

Comment: Maybe they just didn't think it was necessary for this endpoint? Since we didn't develop this API, it's unlikely we can specifically answer.

Comment: @JonStirling The only thing is that in [link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/) they suggest to ask in here..

Comment: @JonStirling Also how it will be able to get more people than 50..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram API never had pagination for user search API, the response has a limited set of user search results, about 50 or so. pagination is just not supported for this endpoint

Comment: So an app can only take at a specific time only these 50 users using instagram api? (Maybe a trivial question just to be certain i understand correctly)

Comment: u can only get 50 users in a search result, u can access any public user using API, if u know the username